# How to clear everything on map

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I am adding markers to my map from my database via an ajax request. This is for a reporting function, so I am querying my database based on date values. The result then adds the markers to the map, and adds a polyline between markers as well.

How can I clear the entire map of all markers and polylines before the function is run? This is my code:

**jQuery**

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-49.7770641, 45.660275],7);
var markerArray = [];
var latlngArray = [];

$( document ).ready(function() { 
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 20,
    }).addTo(map);
    getvehicles();
    var polyline = L.polyline(markerArray, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);  
});
```

**Function that gets markers:**

```
function getlocationsreport(){

  var deviceid = $("#selectid").val();
  var start = $("#start").val();
  var end = $("#end").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functionhandlers/getlocations.php",
            data: {deviceid:deviceid,start:start,end:end},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {

            $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');
            if(!response.errors && response.result) {                               
                $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                    var latlng = L.latLng(value[7], value[8]);
                    markerArray.push(L.circleMarker(latlng,{radius:2}));        
                    latlngArray.push(latlng);                   
               });
                 var group = L.featureGroup(markerArray).addTo(map);
                 var polyline = L.polyline(latlngArray, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map); 
                 map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
            } else {
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                    // add error classes
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });
            }
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the group out of the loop and use clearLayers() method to empty the group.

```
// once for all
var group = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

// in getlocationsreport
group.clearLayers();

// in marker loop
group.add(marker);

// then polyline
group.add(polyline);
```

see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup
and http://plnkr.co/edit/bYFzdmE5FcYe07HnVKLg?p=preview

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks a lot :)